# How do I get the post request with express js?

Tags: node.js, http, post, express

I'm trying to get the post variables in a little service I wrote but cannot seem to get it out of the request variable in my app.post method. I believe it's some way that I'm processing the request. Are there additional steps I must take to process the request?  I've also tried using express.bodyParser() but I got an error saying that this is deprecated.  The following is my little node.js file:

```
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        app.use(express.json());
        // posting method : curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/post-page -d name=ArrowKneeous
        // to look at the req I found it better to start using: 
        // nohup node testPost.js > output.log &
        app.post('/post-page',function(req,res){
        var name= req.body.name;
        //undefined
        console.log('name is :' + name);
        //object
         console.log('req is: '+req);
        //object
        console.log('req.body is: ' +req.body);
        //undefined
        console.log('req.body.name is: '+req.body.name);
        //undefined
         console.log('req.params[0]: '+req.params[0]);
         //undefined
         console.log('req.query.name is: '+req.query.name);
         //empty brackets
         console.dir(req.body);
         //huge
         console.dir(req);
         //got stuff is replied to the curl command
         res.send('got stuff');
       });
    app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

> app.use(express.json());

to process a JSON post, but are POSTing standard URL encoded form data.

> -d name=ArrowKneeous

You either need to post JSON

```
-d '{"name": "ArrowKneeous"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

or you need to tell express to also accept URL encoded POST data.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

#### Edit

This applies to Express `3.x`. It should be almost the same with `4.x`, but you will need to load the `body-parser` module instead:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// OR
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Comment: Great answer, @loganfsmyth.  Most people would just say `app.use(express.bodyParser())`, but I prefer to use `json` or `urlencoded` directly since `multipart` (currently included in `bodyParser`) will be deprecated soon.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I;m trying to use suggested solution : Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately

Comment: @Igal Updated. Keep in mind that Express has a new major version (`4.x`), so any answer older than a month or so may not be accurate.