# Extracting POST parameters from request in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post

I am trying to get parameters from a POST in the variable postData by using the request by - 
( i used this because it was suggested here - [How do I get the post request with express js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003975/how-do-i-get-the-post-request-with-express-js) )

and here -
[How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var json = require('json');
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies

app.post('/shrib/:file/:data',function(req,res){
    var fileName = req.params.file;
    var data = req.params.data;
    req.on('data',function(data){ body+=data; } );
    req.on('end' ,function(){
        var postData = qs.parse(body);
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        var postData = req.body.text;
        if(postData)
            console.log(postData);
        else    
            console.log("failed miserably");
        res.write(200);
        res.end();
    });
});
app.get('/shrib/:file',function(req,res){   
    var fileName = req.params.file;
    if(fileName != ''){
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        var content;
        readStream.on('data',function(chunk){
            content+=chunk.toString();
            console.log(content);
        });
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
            res.write("<form id=\"submitForm\" method=\"POST\">");
            res.write("<textarea id=\"text\"rows=50 cols=50 >");
            console.log(content);
            if(content)
                res.write(content.toString());
            res.write("</textarea>");
            res.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" />");
            res.write("</form>");
            res.write("<script>");
            res.write("var windowLocation = location.href;");
            res.write("document.getElementById(\"submitForm\").action=windowLocation + \'/data\';");
            res.write("</script>");
            res.end();
        });
    }else{
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write("invalid/empty path name"); 
    }
});
app.listen(8080);
```

and got this error -

```
Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/unknown/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
```

I was using body parser before which i read in some solutions here and it gave me the same error middleware missing, i installed it globally then also got the same error and after that i read about json , so i installed it globally using

```
npm install -g json
```

did not work, then too. then i tried adding the dependancies -

```
{
  "name": "express_shrib.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Creating Shrib Using Express",
  "main": "express_shrib.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/iamdeadman/nodejs.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamdeadman/nodejs/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamdeadman/nodejs",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": ">= 1.2.0",
    "json": ">= 9.0.0"
  }
}
```

and ran npm install
still the same error -

```
Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/unknown/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
```

Edit** - Code with the new body-parser module

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());
app.post('/shrib/:file/:data',function(req,res){
    var fileName = req.params.file;
    var data = req.params.data;
    req.on('data',function(data){ body+=data; } );
    req.on('end' ,function(){
        var postData = req.body;
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        if(postData)
            console.log(postData);
        else{   
            console.log("failed miserably");
            console.log(postData);
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    });
});
app.get('/shrib/:file',function(req,res){   
    var fileName = req.params.file;
    if(fileName != ''){
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        var content;
        readStream.on('data',function(chunk){
            content+=chunk.toString();
            console.log(content);
        });
        readStream.on('end',function(){
            res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
            res.write("<form id=\"submitForm\" method=\"POST\">");
            res.write("<textarea id=\"text\"rows=50 cols=50 >");
            console.log(content);
            if(content)
                res.write(content.toString());
            res.write("</textarea>");
            res.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" />");
            res.write("</form>");
            res.write("<script>");
            res.write("var windowLocation = location.href;");
            res.write("document.getElementById(\"submitForm\").action=windowLocation + \'/data\';");
            res.write("</script>");
            res.end();
        });
    }else{
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write("invalid/empty path name"); 
    }
});
app.listen(8080);
```

and here i get

```
{}
```

in the console which means that the body object is empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Express 4, the body parsing middleware (like other previously built-in middleware) was extracted out into the 'body-parser' module. However, this new module only handles JSON and urlencoded form submissions, not multipart.

If you need multipart support, you'd need to use something like [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty) (connect-multiparty is essentially the old Express bodyParser middleware).

EDIT: Also, the `name` attribute is missing for the textarea input field. This is required, otherwise the field will not be sent with the form.

Comment: Okay so i added 
npm install body-parser -g
and then 
app.use(bodyParser()); 
and then tried 
var postData = req.body.text;
console.log(postData);

Comment: But still it gave me undefined in the console.log()

Comment: Okay, on printing req.body i got {} just this, can you suggest why the data from text id is not getting posted

Comment: You should probably post the code you're using now with `body-parser` somewhere.

Comment: I edited my post for the body-parser code, which i found from http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling and https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser though i did not understand why to wrap the parsing code in the use function, is that necessary ? or the way i am doing is correct but the form i am posting in response is wrong

Comment: @deadman Try [this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/686b860ebe245fd07422).

Comment: Oh, yeah it worked. Thanks a lot, was it the quotes that i used in the form that messed the post data or anything else, i did not understand as the body-parser code usage was similar to mine i think

Comment: @deadman It may have been the missing `name` attribute for your textarea field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55283/discussion-between-deadman-and-mscdex).

Answer (score 0):

When using express 4 use body-parser middleware to get parameters.
Multipart has issue that it creates loads of temp files. So its better to avoid it whenever possible and use upload services directly.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var urlParser = require('url');
        var url = urlParser.parse(req.url, true);
        if (url.pathname == "/rest/file/upload") {
            next();
        } else {
            var contentType = req.header("content-type");
            if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") != -1) {
                bodyParser.json({limit: 1024 * 1024 * 10})(req, res, next);
            } else {
                bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: 1024 * 1024 * 10})(req, res, next);
            }
        }
    });
```

then just get your request parameter as :

```
console.log(req.param("parameter-name"));
```